# Probability distribution from randomly selected values of another probability distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I have a probability distribution
$f(x) = c\cdot\exp(-c\cdot x)$
where $c\in\Bbb R$ and $ x \in [0, \infty ) $

I have to make a collection of 5 randomly selected values from this distribution. $ x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4, x_5 $ which are randomly selected based on the probability distribution. (I would expect more frequent values at small $x$ because its more probable.. exponential decay of probability).

Now let's say  $ n = x_1 + x_2 + x_3+ x_4 + x_5 $

What would be the new probability distribution for the collection wrt 'n' i.e. p(n)?

I am not sure how to start. I understand that I could use multiplication of probabilities for a 'n':
$ f(x_1)\cdot f(x_2)\cdots f(x_5) $ but how to include condition of $ x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=n $ to find p$(n)$?

Comment: Consider typing up the math in MathJax, makes it much more readable.

Comment: What you have there is an exponential distribution with density $f(x)$ and intensity $c$. What you seek is the distribution of the $n$-th jump time of a Poisson process. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4348044/949989) how to deal with such problems.

Comment: Note that $f$ is not a probability density on $[0,N]$ as the integral of $f$ over this interval is strictly smaller than $1$. If you consider $f$ on the interval $[0,\infty)$ instead you have the exponential distribution with rate $c$. It is a special case of the Gamma distribution.

Comment: @jakobdt I am basically doing it for [0,infinity), with rate c and I thought it should have area under the curve as 1, in that case. Right?

Comment: @RichardJensen Sorry. I am still looking up, how to format it with MathJax.

Comment: @VipulTomar [Here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) an old guide, but the basics should be the same.

Comment: @RichardJensen Thank you.. Working on it

Comment: I see that it is correct that $f(x)$ is not a probability distribution on $[0,N)$. @VipulTomar What is the point of having this $N$ at all ?

Comment: Okay. I edited the question. I replaced N to infinity. Hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: The class of exponential distributions is contained in the class of Gamma distributions. What is particularly nice about the latter is that the sum $X_1+\dotsm+X_n$ of $n$ independent Gamma distributed random variables $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$ is again Gamma distributed.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. Looks like I was making some huge mistake. So I am looking at it in a different way. So I will post as a new question to not create confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have independence of the samples, and that they are identically exponentially distributed with rate parameter $c$.

**Apply the Law of Total Probability.**

When five non-negative values sum to a non-negative total ($n$), then four have to sum to at most $n$, and the fifth shall be the remainder.

$$\begin{align} p(n) &= \mathbf 1_{0\leqslant n}\cdot{\mathop{\iint\!\!\!\iint}\limits_{s+t+u+v\leq n} f(s)f(t)f(u)f(v)f(n-s-t-u-v)\,\mathrm d v\,\mathrm d u\,\mathrm d t\,\mathrm d s}\\&=\mathbf 1_{0\leq 
n}\cdot\int_0^n\int_0^{n-s}\int_0^{n-s-t}\int_0^{n-s-t-u}c^5\mathrm e^{-c n}\,\mathrm d v\,\mathrm d u\,\mathrm d t\,\mathrm d s\\&~~\vdots\end{align}$$