# Relationship between Poisson and Exponential Distributions

Tags: random-variables, exponential-distribution, poisson-process

I believe these two statements are true:

1. If interarrival times follow an exponential distribution, then the number of arrivals in time period T can be described by the Poisson process.
2. Likewise, if the number of arrivals in time period T follows a Poisson process then the interarrival time is an exponential RV.

Are these two statements effectively 2 sides of the same coin? can someone explain why or why not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Link between Poisson distribution and Exponential distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4347815/link-between-poisson-distribution-and-exponential-distribution)